# Filter time values that are a set period either side of a specified time

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, datediff, date-difference

Given a specified time value and an interval value:

```
Specified Time: 13:25:00
Interval Value: 00:20:00
```

How can I filter the following table of values to return times that are the specified **Interval** either side of the **Specified Time**.

```
12:45:24
13:05:00
13:50:30
14:50:32
15:15:10
```

I want a function or query to check if '13:25:00' has '00:20:00' difference with any of the times in table.

The output should return:

```
13:05:00
```

Comment: Not clear ,some more description needed here

Comment: What makes your time special?

Comment: so you want to find times that are 20 minutes either side of your "special time"... so the output would be: `13:05:00` if you're working to seconds?

Comment: what do you mean by `special` dude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided, I assume you want to get values from the list that are the specified period either side of your "special time".

Here's one way to do it using `DATEADD`:

```
-- temp table for your sample data
CREATE TABLE #times ( val TIME )

INSERT  INTO #times
        ( val )
VALUES  ( '12:45:24' ),
        ( '13:05:00' ),
        ( '13:50:30' ),
        ( '14:50:32' ),
        ( '15:15:10' )

DECLARE @special_time TIME = '13:25:00'      
DECLARE @diff_value TIME = '00:20:00'

-- variable will hold the total number of seconds for your interval
DECLARE @diff_in_seconds INT

-- gets the total number of seconds of your interval -> @diff_value 
SELECT  @diff_in_seconds = DATEPART(SECOND, @diff_value) + 60
        * DATEPART(MINUTE, @diff_value) + 3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, @diff_value)

-- get the values that match the criteria
SELECT  *
FROM    #times
WHERE   val = DATEADD(SECOND, @diff_in_seconds, @special_time)
        OR val = DATEADD(SECOND, -( @diff_in_seconds ), @special_time)

DROP TABLE #times
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause filters the results by adding and subtracting the difference. The subtraction is achieved by making the `@diff_in_seconds` negative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
can you please change it for me to work for this solution
1.my times are inserted in table before, so i want to use select to grab them
2.that special time can be parametric 
3.that X time can be parametric

Comment: @user1998368 I don't really understand what you mean with your requirements. My answer is simply mocking up a table to replicate your data and then selecting from it, so that sounds like it covers point 1. The special time and X time are both declared as variables / parameters, so that sounds like it covers points 2 & 3.

Answer (score 1):

If we are understanding your question correctly, you want all the times that are bigger than 20 minutes from your given (special) time.

To achieve this, just do a select with a where clause that contains a clause looking like this: `abs(datediff(minute, tableDate, @specialdate)) > 20`

[SQLFiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f478e/4) and code example:

```
declare @specialDate datetime = '1900-01-01 13:25:00'

select *
  from SampleData
 where abs(datediff(minute, SomeDate, @specialDate)) > 20
```

Note that I set the dates of the Datetime columns to `1900-01-01` as an obscure reference, adjust according to your settings.

You will need the `ABS` in the line to make sure that both variants of the resulting `datediff` are checked (It can either bring back 0, > 0 or < 0)

References:
[MSDN: DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx)
[MSDN: ABS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
create table t(t time);

insert into t
values
    ('12:45:24'),
    ('13:05:00'),
    ('13:50:30'),
    ('14:50:32'),
    ('15:15:10')

declare @st time = '13:25:00'
declare @dt time = '00:20:00'

select * from t
where abs(datediff(ss, t, @st)) - datediff(ss, '00:00:00', @dt) = 0
```

`abs(datediff(ss, t, @st)` will hold difference in seconds between times in table and special time. You compare this difference to difference between `00:00:00` and interval `datediff(ss, '00:00:00', @dt)`

Output:

```
t
13:05:00.0000000
```

Fiddle   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05df4/1